# Solr Query which shows data from today sorted by date desc and shows future records if no data from today

Tags: solr, lucene

Need to write a solr Query which shows data from today sorted by date desc and if no record available from today to past, then shows future records.
Closest i could get is below query.

```
((entity_handle: * test * AND entity_air_time:[* TO NOW/DAY])    
(entity_handle: "test" AND entity_air_time:[* TO NOW/DAY])^2.0    
(entity_handle:test AND entity_air_time:[* TO NOW/DAY])^1.5)    
 AND is_deleted:false AND is_active:true AND is_root :true
```

And i sort it with entity_air_time desc.

But i need to figure out how to modify query to get future entity_air_time records if i cant get them from "past to today" time span in single query.

Comment: show your CURL query, and the response. Show the relevant parts of schema.xml and sokrconfig.xml

Comment: Any reason why you can't do it in two queries? They'll read the same data and the cache will be primed after the first time you query anyway.

Comment: @matsLindh i am using paging with it so if i use multiple queries i need to manage a threshold of records from both thats why.

Comment: Thank you the requirement has been changed no future records required now.